# XSLT - How do output only the attribute values and ignore the value of the element

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm a rookie with a rookie problem.

I'm trying my hand at an XML -> XSLT -> XML conversion to integrate content created in a vendor platform with a legacy publication channel.

I'm stuck. The input XML document has a value as an attribute that I want as new element text in the output XML document. That I can do, but I want to ignore the value of the element in the origin xml doc and it wont go away!

Thanks for the help. Here is the example:

Input XML
`<author value="Firstname LASTNAME">123456789</author>`

Desired Output XML
`<owner>Firstname LASTNAME</owner>`

Broken XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="author">
    <owner>
        <xsl:value-of select="@display_value" />
    </owner>
    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

xml result of broken XSLT

`<owner>Fistname LASTNAME</owner>123456789`

You see the value of the element from the origin xml document, I want it to disappear. I don't need it. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Remove the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction, if you don't want the child nodes of `author` (in this example, the `"123456789"` text node) to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the `apply-templates` expression from your code will do the task

```
<xsl:template match="author">
    <owener>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </owener>
</xsl:template>
```